# Centering mobile UI

Tags: css, user-interface, mobile, center

I'm fairly new to the web developing/ coding area and looking to develop a website I've built. I'm encountering a few problems with my site, but the main issue I'd like to resolve in this thread is the centering of the content on mobile devices. The content looks fine on desktop but seems to shift to the left and not fill the page on mobile.

See link here: https://loudburr.github.io/louisburr/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you change your banner text CSS to instead of width to max-width that should work

.banner-text {max-width: 600px;}

Comment: Hey Kyara, unfortunately this idea didn't quite work. I'm still trying to fix the issue, do you have any other ideas of what it may be?

Comment: You don't need to add this with a media query. You need to change your overall banner-text element to have a max-width instead of just width.

Answer (score 0):

> I think your "html" code (that I saw in view source page of your site) has some fundamental errors. for example you use a "div" tag in the "head" section of your code. and in line about "50" you have some closed tag that I did not understand that where they started. I suggest that you check your codes in this website: https://validator.w3.org

Comment: Hey Hamid, thanks for reaching out. I've tried using the validator.w3.org site and helped with a few elements, however I'm still unable to center the content on mobile. Do you have any further advice to help?

Comment: centering the contents of web pages (or in other words "making" a web page "responsive") is a topic in web design "itself". and I suggest you to read more about it. with my knowledge level, I think it is usually depends on the "width" of elements in your CSS file. use relative "units" like (%) for width of elements. not using "px" for width and positions. you can also use frameworks like "bootstrap" that could make your work a lot easier.